# ImageView changed size after image change

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView im my layout. Now if I set a new image to it which is bigger than the old one the size of the ImageView change. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifiy `layout_height` and `layout_width` params for the ImageView, and the `scaleType` parameter.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_imageView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/my_image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/my_image_height"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

> Options for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of this view.

Comment: Isn't it simpler like this: `<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>` ?

Comment: @g00dy. Only if they want it to `match_parent`. What if they want it to be 50dp wide only?

Answer (score 0):

use this for adjust the image o image view

```
 imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```